# how can use / in querystring value in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I used ASP.NET MVC5, I have a URL like this:

> localhost:/product/12/nexus5x/quartz

```
product :controller; 12 :id; nexus5x/quartz:name
```

But it's returning a `404` error because the last param in the url contains `/` and I don't have routing to support that.
How can I do this?
Sometimes the last param (`productName`) contains `/`.

The first solution is replace `/` with `-` but for some product I couldn't replace that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the URL. URL encoding involves converting the characters so that they can be included in the query string. The character `/` is encoded to `%2F`.

So the URL will become `/product/12/nexus5x%2Fquartz`

To encode the value in JavaScript you can call the [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) method.

```
var productName = "nexus5x/quartz";
var encodedProductName = encodeURI(productName);
```

To encode the value in C# you can call the `Uri.EscapeUriString` method.

Comment: @osmanRahimi In C# you can use `Uri.EscapeUriString` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you should be able to use a catch all route. Just **prefix an asterisk** '*' to the last token.

Here is an example using Route attribute:

```
[Route("product/{id}/{*name}")]
```

The parameter 'name' here should **catch everything past 'id'**, even if that includes a slash.